# Use the bus stop announcment system to detect whether the user is in the bus or not

Tags: android, microphone

I am implementing an app to track the location of buses based on Crowdsorcing. The riders send data `long, lat, mac, route, timestamp` to the server as JSON string which is being inserted into the bus table. The waiting rider at the stop can query the server to get the location of their diserable route.

The route in the JSON string is not always known so I cant always use it to detect whether the rider is in the bus or not. Therefore, I am trying to use the bus stop announcment system  to determine that. In the bus there is a announcer which notifies the name of the next stop. Is it possiable to recognize this sound with the microphone of the Android device to say the user is in the bus?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: One can steal your Idea now :D

Comment: ... which was obviously ironical.

Comment: @DerGolem: Please can you tell me where is the problem with this question?

Comment: **1** - Where is your code? Are you asking **us** to write it for you? It doesn't work like that, here. **2** - The question is way tooooooo broad to get an answer. **3** - I don't think the idea is feasible for real (too much effort for a small result). **4** - Why should this system be better than a consolidated GPS tracking or the user sending an SMS/eMail/Telegram/WhatsApp/... to inform you? Trust me... work on something better than this.

Comment: @DerGolem: I am not asking for code I am just asking whether the idea is realizable or not!

Comment: Read points **2**, **3**, **4** of the above comment. Anyway, this isn't a site to ask for **advices**. But to ask for **help** about a `non-working code` bit.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly about the idea: "app to track the location of buses based on Crowd sourcing": You should definitely need an active User community to update the details. 
And Second thing: "JSON string is not always known" You addressed the issue here and changed your mind to make use of announcer information. The question is: How to capture the announcer information? I totally understand that people started playing with Siri, Cortana, etc.

Here are few suggestions from my tracking experience: 
1. If you wanna track a bus, the bus should have some kind of inbuilt tracking device which sends Lat,Long information to the server.
2. You must have server side to process these messages.
3. Your app can communicate with the server to get real time information. 
4. There are many bus tracking app's already available in market, you can do a quick search in Play Store.

Definitely, I would not discourage the idea of tracking the real time location of bus; I have personally used different apps to track buses and found useful. But there is no concept of Globalization that you can use a single app to track different Buses running in different states/countries.